# Survival Analysis: Number of Censored Events in Life Table

Tags: r, survival, kaplan-meier

I want to construct a life table for some event of interest. See below for an example:

[image]

I'm trying to do this with `survival` R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf.

```
surv <- Surv(veteran$time, veteran$status)
km <- survfit(surv~trt, data = veteran)
summary(km, censored = TRUE)
```

Notice that I specified `censored = TRUE`. Specifying this option should make the censoring times included in the output.

It prints `time`, `n.risk`, `n.event`, `survival`, `std.err`, `lower 95% CI`, and `upper 95% CI`. However, it doesn't print `n.exit.censored` as expected. I'm trying to figure out why it's not printing the a number censored column. I downloaded the latest version of `survival` package.

```
packageVersion("survival")
```

Prints

```
[1] ‘2.43.3’
```

Is this happening for anyone else?

Comment: As this question is on R code rather than on a statistical issue per se, it's off topic on this site. Try posting to an R help site instead. Even if there is no `n.exit.censored` column in your output, note that the output with `censored=TRUE` includes times of censoring (e.g., see time=25 for trt=1 output from your code) so that it should be easy to get the numbers censored at each time by difference.